# Where can I write code that runs constantly?

Tags: swift, xcode, methods, sprite-kit

In my SpriteKit game, I've been declaring some variables and other things (like SKTextures) first-thing in the GameScene (as class-level variables). However, I want to constantly check for whether a sprite's position is in a specific area.

Is there a specific method that's always being called? Or do I have to write the code in a very special place?

Comment: This is a conceptual question, he's trying to understand the mechanics and procedures of SpriteKit, specifically where per-frame logic occurs and can be coded to/at/with. I don't see how this could possibly be unclear to anyone reading it, despite Justin's absence of terminology knowledge, he's been pretty clear about his question.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure those that have voted to close all know what he's asking, but have voted to close because he's not used the terminology of someone that knows the system, framework and game making. That's just snobbery. @Sweeper has directly answered the question. So it's neither an unclear question, nor a question without an answer. Check yourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a specific method that runs all the time!

It's called `update`. You can override this in your `SKScene` subclass like this

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // write your code here...
}
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skscene/1519802-update):

> Override this to perform per-frame game logic. Called exactly once per frame before any actions are evaluated and any physics are simulated.
>
> Do not call this method directly; it is called exactly once per frame, so long as the scene is presented in a view and is not paused. By default, this method does nothing. Your scene subclass should override this method and perform any necessary updates to the scene.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Sweeper, please see my comments below the question. Can you suggest how I'd rewrite the question to get it "approved" by the "powers that be"?

Comment: @Confused I have already voted for reopening. I'll try to edit the question later